# Is there a built-in way to rotate all values in a matrix (nalgebra)?

Tags: rust, nalgebra

Left rotation example:

```
[1,2] -> [2,4] -> [4,3]
[3,4] -> [1,3] -> [2,1]
```

Is there a built-in way to do this? if not, what's a simple alternative solution?

Answer (score 1):

That can be implemented as a reflection and a transpose, e.g.:

```
matrix![0, 1;
        1, 0] * m.transpose()
```

Comment: very cool – and to rotate right you transpose after multiplying